Time series and separating variance by time scale
There is a single-variable time series wich can be thought as being stationary in the long run.  The observations are taken at irregular time intervals.  The values of observations can be assumed to have no overall trend, but the process probably has a few forcing functions that operate at different frequencies (i.e. the short-term variability at the scale of minutes may have different causes from the longer-term variability at the scale of hours and days).
I'm interested in trying to separate the magnitude of variance caused by those different processes - the short-term variability is likely caused by the instrument/method uncertainty and imprecision and the longer-term variability is the product of the intrinsic variability of the process being measured (but there is not much other specific information on the nature of the process variability other than it is hopefully larger than the uncertainty of the method used to measure it and that it likely operates on the longer time scale).
What would be a good place to start assessing what part of the variance is caused by the measurement imprecision vs. what results from changes in the underlying variable?

This sounds like a good candidate for a State-Space model, where you simultaneously model the underlying dynamics of the true process as well as the observation process. In State-Space models, both of these processes can incorporate regressors and variance components, allowing you to use domain knowledge to make inferences about possible mechanisms that influence the phenomenon you are interested in and the way in which that phenomenon is measured (usually with error). For unevenly spaced time series, you may need to either pad the observations with NAs where there was no observation but where the process has continued to evolve, or you may need to use a proper dynamic model that captures uneven spacing in the process model (such as a continuous time autoregressive model).
I maintain a small R package that can construct and fit these models using Bayesian inference. Not sure if it is what you are after but some of the vignettes might be of particular use to introduce concepts and point you to further reading materials. See for example the shared latent states vignette and the multivariate State-Space models vignette.
